# Folder URL screwing up due to .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

In my htaccess I have the following code:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ category.php?parent=$1
```

The code works perfectly for what I want and makes pretty urls for categories as I'm sure you're all aware.

The only issue I am having is that I have created a folder called 'about' on my server. In the about folder, I have an index.html file which I want to display. If you try to access the url at site.com/about/ then the page is displayed and the url stays exactly the same.

But, if somebody accesses the url at site.com/about then they are automatically redirected to site.com/about/?parent=about. Somebody is going to access it at this url and then google will probably end up indexing it and cause duplicate pages.

I know this is due to the htaccess, but I don't understand why it is happening like it is and how would I go about fixing it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trailing `/` in `about/` is not caught by the regex in your .htaccess, but `about` is, being composed only by `a-z` characters.

Add this just before your rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/about/?$
```

And your about URL will not be rewritten.

Anyway, consider using a safer URL scheme, such as `/category/somename`: what if a user wants to create a category named "about"?

More about conditions [here](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteCond)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm actually just throwing up an about page for a few weeks as I a page to demo the site but you make a good point which I will consider in future. Thanks again.